# Python: List of pairs. Making every pair single and sum the values of the same keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of pairs.The list contains items of [x,y].I would like to make list or dictionary making the left item the key and right the value.The list maybe contains multiple times the same key. I want to sum the values and keep one time the key.
E.x
`pairs[0]=['3106124650', 2.86]`
`pairs[1]=['3106124650', 8.86]`
 pairs[2]=['5216154610', 23.77]

I want to keep  '3106124650' one time and sum the values.So my new list or dictionary will contain one time this key with value 11.72.
 '3106124650',11.72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
sumdict = dict()
for i, v in pairs:
    sumdict[i] = v + sumdict.get(i, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way. For large datasets, numpy will probably be faster though.

```py
import collections
result = collections.defaultdict(lambda : 0)
for k,v in pairs:
    result[k]+=v
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li=[['a',1],['a',2],['b',3],['c',4]]
d={}
for w in li:
    d[w[0]]=w[1]+d.get(w[0],0)

Output:{'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
d={}
for entry in pairs:
    if entry[0] in d:
        d[entry[0]]+=entry[1]
    else:
        d[entry[0]]=entry[1]
```